# Function to allow "Anyone can register"?

Tags: customization, users, user-registration

I'd been crawling the codex but can't seem to find a function that will allow me to programmatically enable the User registration system. Hopefully, I can make a custom plugin that will enable User registration system by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using this code:

```
add_action('init', 'update_anyone_can_register');
function update_anyone_can_register() {
  update_option('users_can_register', true);
}
```

I tested on my `functions.php` file and it worked as expected.

Comment: Note that this will update the option and write to the database on every page load

Comment: @TomJNowell what I did is: `if ( ! get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) { update_option( 'users_can_register', true ); }`